# How to use substitution variables in Oracle APEX

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, substitution-variables

I've tried everything I can find on the internet but something's just not working.  I've heard that you can use substitution variables in Oracle APEX SQL Workshop by putting a string that starts with an ampersand like so: `SELECT * FROM orders WHERE shipstate = '&state';`, and it will ask you what you want to put as that string when you run the code.  I cannot make this happen.  I believe when I run the code, it is just treating the '&state' like a regular string.  How do I make it treat it as a substitution string?  I've already tried removing the single quotes, adding a period to the end, and a combination of both.  This is in Oracle APEX workspace:

[image: Oracle APEX]

Answer (score 1):

If bind (instead of substitution) variable is OK to you, use it.

```
select * from orders where shipstate = :state;
```

It will prompt you for `state` value.

Comment: This is great! What's the difference?  Too bad I can't use it though :( this is for schoolwork that requires me to use substitution variables.

Comment: Difference? BluShadow (here: https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2477546/substitution-vs-bind-variable) explained it well, with examples - have a look. As of your assignment: if you used some **other tool** (i.e. not Apex SQL Workshop but SQL*Plus or SQL Developer or TOAD ...), you could use substitution variables. SQL Workshop doesn't support them.